# some quick PHP and HTML help

Tags: php, html

Basically I will tell you what I want to do.

1: If a user is not logged in I want them to be re-directed back to the login page.

2: If a user is Logged in and they submitted a form I want them to be directed to the next page.

I have tried it with meta refresh but I can only seem to get it working with one or the other.

Can you please advise what the best way to do this would be ?

the code I am using at the moment is

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;index.php">  
<meta http-equiv="refresh" name="myidentifier" content="0;mystats.php">
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you're using now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use http headers instead. For example:

```
session_start();

//Redirect when user is not logged
if($_SESSION['logged'] != 1)
{
  header("Location: http://redirect.here.com/login.php");
  exit(0);
}

//Redirect when user sent form
if((isset($_POST['sent']))&&($_SESSION['logged']==1))
{
  header("Location: http://redirect.here.com/nextpage.php");
  exit(0);
}
```

Don't forget to set `$_SESSION['logged']=1` after successful login.
There are more methods of detecting that user sent form, but I prefer placing hidden input field with `name="sent"` to each form.

Comment: I wouldn't use meta tags for redirect purpose when you can use http headers instead. I think it's always better to avoid using meta tags when there is http header equivalent.

Comment: You don't need the meta refresh (which is bad practice alltogether).

Comment: The else-block code can be in the main scope of the function.  Because the if-block code exits, it is a guard clause.

Comment: You are right Ewan, but I think it's more human readable with 'else'.

I edited the answer to cover both parts and deleted the 'else' block anyway.

Comment: I am getting the following error "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"

Comment: You must make sure that you didn't send any output before calling header() function. Note that even space before '<?php' tag can be considered as output.